# How to render days as links for jQuery datepicker?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I would like to turn the days in datepicker into links. How can I do that? I know it has `onSelect`, but that doesn't give visual clues to users when they mouse over the days.

I tried the following but it does seem to execute the callback function. using jQuery UI v1.9.2 and jQuery v1.8.1.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        renderCallback: function ($td, thisDate, month, year) {
            alert('hi');
        }
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

Even the workarounds are easy to implement, I decided to go with Kevin B's approach. Here's the whole thing.

```
var old_generateHTML = $.datepicker._generateHTML;
$.datepicker._generateHTML = function () {
    function getMonth(s) {
        var months = {
            'January': '01', 'February': '02', 'March': '03', 'April': '04', 'May': '05', 'June': '06',
            'July': '07', 'August': '08', 'September': '09', 'October': '10', 'November': '11', 'December': '12'
        }
        return months[s];
    }
    var ret = old_generateHTML.apply(this, arguments);
    var month = ret.replace(/^.*month">([a-z]+)<\/span.*$/i, "$1");
    var year = ret.replace(/^.*year">([0-9]{4})<\/span.*$/i, "$1");
    ret = ret.replace(/href="#">([0-9]{1,2})<\/a>/g, "href=\"process.php?date=" + getMonth(month) + "/$1/" + year + "\">$1</a>");
    return ret;
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

Comment: visual clues is what CSS is for, though hovering on days looks link behavior on default.

Comment: @eric.itzhak, I meant when user mouse over a day, the user can see the actual link.

Comment: Which version of jQuery UI? it's going to take extending the datepicker to get this kind of functionality.

Comment: What exactly do you mean "days as links"?

Comment: When you hover over December 1st for example (the little box that represents it) he wants that to be a link. It already is a link (i think), but he wants its href set to a particular url so that when you hover over it, you can see the url in the bottom left.

Comment: You would have to override the `_generateHTML` method (defined at `$.datepicker.prototype._generateHTML`) at line 1593 of https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js. The lines in particular that you are interested are lines 1750-1751.

Comment: You can either replace the method, or extend it so that the original runs, then you modify it's output. Just keep in mind that the method MUST return html. RegExp would be able to do it using the extend solution, but the most efficient way to fix it (performance-wise) would be to just replace the method, however that won't be future proof.

Comment: The problem is, replacing the `href` will cause the page to reload in many instances. I just tested in jsFiddle with theory and everytime i click a date, the page reloads.

Comment: @SpYk3HH I was under the impression that's what he wants (based off of the first three sentences in question).

Comment: I think I might have found a not so hackish way to do it, updated my answer. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest extending the `generateHTML` method so that every time the html for the datepicker is generated, your links are created.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/C4jWz/1/

```
var old_generateHTML = $.datepicker._generateHTML;

$.datepicker._generateHTML = function() {
    var ret = old_generateHTML.apply(this,arguments);
    ret = ret.replace(/href="#">([0-9]{1,2})<\/a>/g, "href=\"process.php?day=$1\">$1</a>");
    return ret;    
};

//<a class="ui-state-default ui-state-hover" href="#">13</a>

$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
```

This one in particular only gets the day, the month/year can be obtained the same way.

Comment: month and year are actually part of `ret` after calling `old_generateHTML.apply`, and they are inside the `<span class='datepicker-month'>` and `<span class=datepicker-year'>`.

Comment: @RayCheng Kinda like this: http://jsfiddle.net/C4jWz/2/ now you just have to replace "November" with it's digit counterpart.

Comment: when I click on the links, it doesn't go anywhere.

Comment: Right, because jQuery UI Datepicker prevents the default action on those links to prevent it jumping to the top of the page. you'll have to either undo that binding, or bind to it yourself and redirect.

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/C4jWz/3/ i extended the _attachHandlers method to remove the event.

Answer (score 1):

If I get what you mean, then you only need add the following to your CSS:

```
.ui-datepicker td a {
    text-decoration: underline !important;
    color: #1122CC !important; /* For a more traditional Blue use '#0000FF' */
}
```

You can easily change the links of all the Dates with something like:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker().on("click", function(e) { //  must be done on input click as the div is recreated everytime
    $(".ui-datepicker td a").each(function(i) { //  filters through each date
        //  the following grabs the href property and replaces the # tag with the text (aka. the date)
        $(this).prop("href", $(this).prop("href").replace("#", $(this).text()))
        //  I think this could easily be shortened to:
        //  $(this).prop("href", $(this).text()) 
    })
})
```

## **jsFiddle**




## **another Example <sub>in this ver I add a Title attribute to each one</sub>**

- *Note*: The only thing I have found you can't really edit is the text. The text is used to determine the Date.

> ***UPDATE***

It's a little hackish in that I have to use a small timer (really shouldnt be an issue), but I found a way to deal with continueing the change on Clicking to change month and/or year. The reason for the timer is simple, rendering. The "new" days arn't rendered till a split second after the even takes place, thus the reason for the timer.

> The *NEW* Script

```
function updateDates() {
    $(".ui-datepicker td a").each(function(i) {
        $(this).prop("href", $(this).prop("href").replace("#", $(this).text()))
    });
}

$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, inst) {
        setTimeout(function() { updateDates(); }, 500);
    }
}).on("click", function(e) {
    $(".ui-datepicker td a").each(function(i) {
        updateDates();
    })
});
```

## the **New** Example

Comment: That would make the click work, but it still won't show the href at the bottom. That would have to be done on mouseenter. Nice solution though.

Comment: @KevinB Maybe I'm missing somethings, Cause when I go to it in the fiddle, every date I hover over shows the link at the bottom with the Date as the last character of the link. What am I not quite getting? LoL :P

Comment: I do see a problem though, your code has the same problem that eric's code does. Once you click next or change the year/month, your code needs to be ran again.

Comment: @KevinB I can fix that, gimmie 5 mins ... or less

Comment: @KevinB Fixed the issue, tho not my favorite fix. perhaps there is a slightly better method, but i dont have time right now.

Comment: you should be able to take that settimeout down to probably 50ms or less, making it virtually instant. I prefer this kind of fix to one like my own because mine will affect all datepickers on the page and may require more maintenance.

Comment: Yeah you can take that delay all the way down to 0. All it needs is to be in a different scope that gets processed after the existing scope.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to do something like this (not tested, mostly logic):

```
$('#datepicker .ui-state-default').each( function() { // i think only the days 
//have this class, you can try and use 'ui-state-default a' 
// or something like that
var thisText = $(this).text();
var href = checkWhichLinksIsThis(thisText);
$(this).attr('href', href);
});
```

Which basically i did here is iterate through all the days link, check by text which one is it
with the `checkWhichLinkIsThis` method and change the href accordingly.

Hope this sets you in the general direction.

Comment: While this may work, i think it would have to be ran every time a month or year is changed, every time the datepicker is opened, etc due to how the datepicker widget was built.

Comment: hmm this might be true i didn't really look into it. it is an ugly workaround i agree but i guess he wouldn't want to change core jquery UI code.